# two spark-Context instance how to work in Worker node and Driver ?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

There are two spark-context  created into application. how it work in spark master node and worker node and driver node?

Comment: No, only one spark context gets created per application. And that's on the driver

Comment: @ernest_k You can have few SparkContexts in one submitted application

Comment: @OP: It's unclear what exactly you want to know. How does they cooperate? How scheduling works?